# MVC RedirectToAction not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have web page with the following HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete Study", "DeleteStudy", "Study", new {topic = @Model.Study.PartitionKey, subtopic = @Model.Study.RowKey}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
        @Html.ActionLink("View Studies", "StudyList", "Study", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })    
    </div>
```

When the DeleteStudy link is clicked, the following controller method is called:

```
    [Authorize]
    public void DeleteStudy(string topic, string subtopic)
    {
        ...
        ...
        RedirectToAction("StudyList");
    }
```

The DeleteStudy method is called and executes successfully, except for the Redirect. No redirect occurs. The StudyList method (which has an Authorization attribute) is never called. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nothing in the code you have shown suggests it should not work. However a Delete action should really be a POST, not a GET (you don't want this added to the browser history or allow the user to enter it in the address bar. At best it just making an unnecessary call to delete something which no longer exist, and at worst may throw an exception depending on your code)

Comment: Actually there is an error - it should be `return RedirectToAction("StudyList");`

Comment: even search engines can delete your data while indexing if am not wrong

Comment: @StephenMuecke - You are correct, and this works. If you wrap this in an answer, I'll accept it. I'll also probably change my code based on comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change

```
RedirectToAction("StudyList");
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("StudyList");
```

However I recommend you make your Delete action a POST rather that a GET. You don't want this added to the browser history or allow the user to enter it in the address bar. At best it's just making an unnecessary call to delete something which no longer exists, and at worst may throw an exception depending on your code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteStudy", "Study", new {topic = Model.Study.PartitionKey, subtopic = Model.Study.RowKey }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <input type="submit" value="Delete Study" /> // style it to look like a link if that's what you want
}
```

and change the method to

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteStudy(string topic, string subtopic)
```

Comment: It needs to be public ActionResult DeleteStudy(...)